# Unable to fetch data using name and zipcode for Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Would you please let me know how to use facebook API for find all business data('address', website, phone, email and so on)using business "Name" and "Zipcode"?

Currently I used like this :
$response = $fb->get('username?fields=id,name,emails,location,phone,website,link');

But instead of "username" i need to pass business "Name" and zipcode and based on this fetch the data.

Please let me know if you have any soultion.

Thanks

Comment: did you take a look at the docs already? specifically he search api? there is no search for zipcode though.

Comment: Yes, But instead of username we need to specify the business name but it's not working. Would you please suggest the API with example ?

Comment: again, search for the search api in the docs. you can´t just pass the business name.